# Login Password, Grub Password or Bios Password

Tags: grub2, password, 20.04, login-screen, bios

I found that Ubuntu login password can be easily reset as mentioned in this article: [Reset Your Forgotten Ubuntu Password in 2 Minutes or Less](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/)

I was wondering if there are alternatives to this. Is setting grub password or UEFI/Bios password more secure than Ubuntu login password?

If its not that secure, then I think I should set up password at the bios (or grub) as I don't want to wait for the login screen to show up later? Any pros and cons of this?

---

Edit: I have dual boot computer with Windows 10. Does setting up grub password , creates any issue due to this?

Comment: I am not sure, but think bios or grub password just stops anybody from changing the settings.  Most of these are for people who have your computer(stopping them from changing).  If worried about your data, then best to encrypt your hard drive.  You must always know the password/pass phase, or it will stop you from getting your data also.  Lose password, lose data.  Can google hard drive encryption for more information.

Comment: You have password for Win10.  When in Ubuntu see how easy to see and/or copy data from Win10 without the password.  Passwords just a sign saying don't touch.